# Clojure shortcuts for destructuring maps

Tags: clojure

This question just came up for me as I was learning about using the shortcut `:keys` for destructuring a map.

Suppose i have the following map:

```
(def my-hashmap {:a "A" :b "B" :c "C" :d "D"})
```

Now i can refer to the values writing

```
(let [{first-key :a second-key :b} my-hashmap] 
    (println first-key second-key))
```

and i get `A B`. Now using `:keys` the keys have to be the same as the original ones (without `:`), or otherwise clojure returns `nil`? So, for

```
(let [{:keys [first-key second-key]} my-hashmap] 
    (println first-key second-key))
```

you get `nil nil`.

Am i seeing this wrong or is really this un-logical thing happening in clojure, because both methodes were meant to refer to the keys and thus should work in the same manner? But they don't, because if I write `(let [{:keys [a b]} my-hashmap] (println a b))` I get again the right answer!

Comment: What would you expect `first-key` and `second-key` to be bound to in `(let [{:keys [first-key second-key]} my-hashmap] (println first-key second-key))`? Keys in a map are not ordered so you have to bind them by name.

Comment: well i thought they should be ordered? i mean whats then exactly the difference between `(let [{:keys [a b]} my-hashmap] (println a b))` and `(let [{:keys [first-key second-key]} my-hashmap] (println first-key second-key))`, because in both cases `a b` and `first-key second-key` are new symbols being just introduced? So does clojure look at `a b` and think these look similar like the original keys, so they are accepted?! (which i don't think is the case!)

Comment: i found the example here: https://gist.github.com/john2x/e1dca953548bfdfb9844 (under Shortcuts)

Comment: The `keys` form looks for keyword keys in the given map and binds them to the corresponding names. `(let [{:keys [a b]} m)` will bind `a` to the value for the key `:a` and `b` to the key `:b` in `m`. So yes, the binding is done by name and not position since there is no notion of ordering for the keys in a hash-map.

Comment: hm, its kind of strange...

Comment: It is not strange, that is exactly what a hash map is in nearly any language: unordered key-value pairs that you access by key explicitly, not by sorted position... Because there is no sorted position.

Answer (score 4):

Your requirement to `:keys` in the second example can't be met because there is no way to deduce which individual keys should be looked up to have their values bound to the arbitrary symbols you are using.

Notice that maps are associative, but not ordered data structures. Hence if you wish to use different names, they need to be mapped to the names and types their values can be looked up at in the destructored map, as you did in your first example.

You can use both symbols and keywords in the `:keys` vector that have fully qualified names of keywords in the map. Futhermore, `:syms` and `:strs` are available to destructor against keys which are symbols or strings.

Answer (score -1):

Amir,

Not the specific answer to the question however; maps implement `Iterable`so you can potentialy create a scheme to work with maps without knowing the key names:

```
(defn map-sequence-example
  [& [[[k v] kp2 & remaining] :as mymap] ]
  (println "first key = " k " first value = " v)
  (println "next key pair = " kp2)
  (println "remaining = " remaining)
  (println "mapseq = " mymap))

(map-sequence-example (seq {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}))

first key =  :a  first value =  1
next key pair =  [:b 2]
remaining =  ([:c 3])
mapseq =  (([:a 1] [:b 2] [:c 3]))
```

Comment: The problem here (and what's meant when people say " there is no notion of ordering for the keys in a hash-map") is that by adding a new key to the map, you can cause the order of the keys to be changed completely.

Comment: `(def m {:a 0 :b 1 :c 2 :d 3 :e 4 :f 5 :g 6 :h 7 :i 8})` `(keys m)` => `(:e :g :c :h :b :d :f :i :a)`; `(keys (assoc m :j 9))` => `(:e :g :c :j :h :b :d :f :i :a)`

Comment: Yes, key order has standard disclaimer, but the processing as in the example I provided does not depend on order or, for that matter, how many k/v there are.

Comment: This is seq destructoring, not map destructoring. It does not answer the question. What is the point?

Comment: Really Leon? The point is an alternative using sequencing to destructure the map in cases where the keys are unknown. It is also foundational to a more dynamic inferencing or key identification contrary to the first paragraph in your response.