# Destructing a map (using the let keyword)

Tags: dictionary, clojure, destructor

As I understand it, the `let` keyword, locally binds variables to values (supporting some sort of pattern matching). It receives two arguments. First is a vector with the symbol we want to bind and the value we want bound. Then comes an expression that uses that value.

In this example, first the variable `person` is defined:

```
user=> (def person {:name "Jabba" :profession "Gangster"})
#'user/person
```

now suppose we want to destruct the map using the `let` function:

```
user=> (let [{name :name} person] (str "The person's name is " name))
"The person's name is Jabba"
```

Why is it that in `[{name :name} person]`, `:name` should necessarily appear after the variable `name`? This actually wouldn't work:

```
user=> (let [{:name name} person] (str "The person's name is " name))
"The person's name is "
```

Why is the order like this? I thought that maps could be defined in either order:

```
user=> (def map1 {:a 1})
#'user/map1
user=> (def map2 {1 :a})
#'user/map2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clojure shortcuts for destructuring maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220308/clojure-shortcuts-for-destructuring-maps)

Comment: `map1` and `map2` are far from identical: in `map1`, the key is `:a`, whereas in the latter the key is `1`. Otherwise your question looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220308/clojure-shortcuts-for-destructuring-maps

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that maps could be defined in either order:

```
user=> (def map1 {:a 1})
#'user/map1
user=> (def map2 {1 :a})
#'user/map2
```

No.

`map1` has one element; with the key `:a` and the value `1`.
`map2` has one element; with the key `1` and the value `:a`.

It's not the same.

Answer (score 1):

1. in a map, ordering of entry values is VERY IMPORTANT; first guy is key, second is value.
2. if you don't like to repeat yourself, you can use below syntax to destructure one or more entries in a map:

   `(let [{:keys [name profession]} person] (str "The person's name is " name ", and job is " profession))`